# Retrieve file name from a html file form element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a form element like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadform" method="post"  action="upload.php"      target="upload_target" onsubmit="startUpload();">
 <input id="file" name="file" type="file" class="target"/>
```

The user inputs a file-name - let's say it's "The Beatles - Revolution.mp3". Is there a way I can grab that from the input form element file after they select a file and display it in a DIV?

Comment: not from the input, because its value resets after submission. but you can either output it back in the php response in some hidden element or var and grab it from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I didn't misunderstand, but how about:

```js
$("#songFile").on("change", function(e) {
   var s = $(this).val().split("\\");
   $("#result").text("You've selected - " + s[s.length - 1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="songFile" />
<div id="result"></div>
```